# Upper UIView blocks UIGestureRecognizer to lower UIViews

Tags: uiview, transparent, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIView subclass that has several images in an L shape, and so it doesn't cover the entire screen.  On my screen I have two of these views layered on top of each other, and each has a UIGestureRecognizer on them.  The top view accepts gestures normally, however if I grab in the transparent space in the "top right" of the L, with the bottom one visible underneath, the bottom one does not recieve the gesture.  Indeed the top one does, but rejects it as I've used gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch: to reject that touch.

Both gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: and gestureRecognizerShouldBegin: both return YES.

[image: Stacked views]

The blue view scales, rotates and pans normally, but the red on can only be selected in the far top and far right, where there is no overlay with the blue view